# portable lightweight java orm framework for android

Tags: java, android, orm, frameworks, portability

I am developing a portable library on Java which will run on mobile device (android, blackberry) and I am looking for a lightweight ORM framework that i can use.  Here is a [list of ORM frameworks](http://java-source.net/open-source/persistence) I found from Google. I've used only hibernate and I'm not familiar with most of them so any advice on which ORM framework I should use? Here are my requirements:

1. The framework must be on java2me
2. Must run on android, android wraps database connection so connection is not directly accessible and some frameworks use the connection.
3. Must be portable

Any help will be great.

Comment: I was going to talk about ORMLite (http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/) which is a portable and lightweight but it's not "java2me" compatible.  What does it mean anyway?

Comment: j2me stands for java micro edition. Java ME (formerly J2ME) technologies contain a highly optimized Java Runtime Environment, that specifically addresses the vast consumer space. Java ME technologies cover a wide range of extremely tiny commodities, and enable security, connectivity, and useful utility programs inside smart cards, pagers, set-top boxes, and other small appliances.

Comment: Can you try to run ormlite in your environment and see how it works?  I don't have access to J2ME to check it out.  http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/ definitively works with the native Android DB calls.  What database does the blackberry OS support?

Comment: I have a quick look at ormlite doc and it uses annotations to configure the classes for mapping and j2me does not support annotations :(.

Comment: ORMLite also allows you to configure your objects using code.  Here's the javadocs for the DatabaseTableConfig http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/DatabaseTableConfig.html