# Is Hibernate an overkill for an Android application?

Tags: java, android, performance, hibernate

I'm looking for a good ORM for my android application and at first glance it seems like for a mobile device I would prefer to use something simpler maybe. The thing is I'm just assuming here with no real evidence, so I thought I would ask the community's opinion (maybe there's is someone that has been through the experience). It is a fairly large(for mobile) application and will be run on a dedicated tablet.

What does everyone else think ? Is Hibernate too much for an android application ? Will there be performance problems ?

What would you use instead if you think it is too much ?

I am aware there are other questions asking for alternatives, but I decided to ask since most of those questions simply assumed it was an overkill and asked for other options and I started wondering "Is it really and overkill ? Why ?" Due to my lack of experience I simply think it it, but can't really provide an answer if I'm asked to explain why. Is it performance ? Is it too much configuration (Which I don't mind) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I'd like to recommend my [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) package.  It was designed to be *much* less heavy compared to Hibernate (and iBatis).  I think that Hibernate *is* too much for Android applications -- especially considering the size of the code and the number of dependencies.

The [Android port of ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) makes direct calls to the Android database API.  A number of applications have been delivered using ORMLite successfully.

Hibernate provides a number of features that cannot be supported by the Android database calls so you will be paying for complexity that you cannot even use.  I'm also not sure it has a native Android backend.  Using SQLite over JDBC is not officially supported by Android and I was unable to get it to work reliably.

Comment: Actually I ended up using ORMLite and just for posterity as you said, let me just say I recommend it 100%. It has great features, it is open source and has an active community.

Comment: @Gray What about this [GreenDAO far better then ORMLite](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/).

Comment: I'm not an Android programmer so I won't comment.  I hear that the stats they are quoting are optimized to make look GreenDAO look good but I'm not surprised it is faster @Shubh.

Comment: Does ormLite support JPA annotations and implement JPA interface, or it has its own?

Comment: It supports a subset of the annotations.  It does not implement the interfaces @Sunnyday.

Answer (score 12):

Yes hibernate is too much & others have searched for alternatives.

Read here:

- [portable lightweight java orm framework for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563945/portable-lightweight-java-orm-framework-for-android)
- [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)
- [Light weight alternative to Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296587/light-weight-alternative-to-hibernate)

Pick yours. :-)

Answer (score 6):

There are quite a few questions similar to yours already. Start with:

- [ORM on android SQLite and database scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973982/)
- [Any Good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/)
- [Light weight alternative to Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296587/)
- [Are there any good ORMs (preferably JPA implementations) that support SQLite (on Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045405/are-there-any-good-orms-preferably-jpa-implementations-that-support-sqlite-on)
- [Higher level database layer for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842357/higher-level-database-layer-for-android)
- [Android object handling / persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794891/android-object-handling-persistence)

though some of those questions might be outdated by now.

Comment: Do these duplicate questions get closed soon after or are they left open forever? I assume not, since there are a few duplicates in your post as well. It would be nice to have moderators roll a lot of those into one question (assuming they're very similar).

Comment: @McStretch: not sure what you're asking. By "these duplicates," do you mean this current question? There isn't a single vote to close on it yet. No votes to close on the ones I linked, either.

Comment: Yeah in general if the answers to questions are links to other posts, then wouldn't it seem appropriate to point this question to a pre-existing one? Voting to close is fine, but I think it should be taken one step further and rolled into the previous questions or something. It's not a big deal or anything, I'm relatively new so I'm asking a more experienced SO user what generally happens with duplicate questions.

Comment: @McStretch: best place to ask is http://meta.stackoverflow.com