# Tutorials for using Hibernate in Android?

Tags: android, hibernate

Could someone point out good tutorials/books for learning how to use/configure Hibernate in Android ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AFAIK, Hibernate does not work on Android. Hibernate is designed for servers and JDBC, not Android devices and on-board SQLite.

Please see:

- [Is Hibernate an overkill for an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257374/is-hibernate-an-overkill-for-an-android-application)
- [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)

Comment: I looked at the links, thanks @CommonsWare. However it seems to me that they were discussing lightweights alternatives to Hibernate in Android, but they never explicitly said that Hibernet 'cannot' be used, or should not be used on very specific requirements. Is that really the case ?

Comment: @Sergio: Considering that the Hibernate site itself says it needs the JVM and does not discuss Android at all, Hibernate most likely does not work on Android.

Comment: So, can anyone tell me how Greenify work on Android? Does it actually hibernate other apps? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh the question and the answer here are about the ORM framework called `Hibernate`, not about hibernating other apps or the phone itself.