# Hibernate Session Factory Android

Tags: java, android, hibernate

I'm trying to use Hibernate on Android.  (Eclipse Android 2.2 SDK)
It seems there is a compile error in line containing

```
HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Here's HibernateUtility Class:

```
public class HibernateUtility {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

The compile error in eclipse is:

> The type javax.naming.Referenceable cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class files

I've copied a file rt.jar from my java sdk (Sun JDK macosx) which contains the package javax.namaing.* and the compile error seems to be solved. But I now get the runtime error below from Android SDK Logcat.

> 08-30 15:21:05.123: W/dalvikvm(240): VFY: unable to find class
>   referenced in signature (Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory;) 08-30
>   15:21:05.123: I/dalvikvm(240): Could not find method
>   org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession, referenced from method
>   com.example.testfordatabase.EtityDao.insert 08-30 15:21:05.123:
>   W/dalvikvm(240): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 102:
>   Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory;.openSession
>   ()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session; 08-30 15:21:05.123: D/dalvikvm(240):
>   VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x000b 08-30 15:21:05.123:
>   D/dalvikvm(240): VFY: dead code 0x000e-003f in
>   Lcom/example/testfordatabase/EtityDao;.insert
>   (Lcom/example/testfordatabase/entity;)V 08-30 15:21:05.123:
>   D/step1(240): Step1 08-30 15:21:05.133: E/dalvikvm(240): Could not
>   find class 'org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration', referenced from method
>   com.example.testfordatabase.HibernateUtility. 08-30
>   15:21:05.133: W/dalvikvm(240): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 65
>   (Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;) in
>   Lcom/example/testfordatabase/HibernateUtility; 08-30 15:21:05.133:
>   D/dalvikvm(240): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000 08-30
>   15:21:05.133: D/dalvikvm(240): VFY: dead code 0x0002-000f in
>   Lcom/example/testfordatabase/HibernateUtility;. ()V 08-30
>   15:21:05.133: W/dalvikvm(240): VFY: unable to find class referenced in
>   signature (Lorg/hibernate/SessionFactory;) 08-30 15:21:05.133:
>   W/System.err(240): Initial SessionFactory creation
>   failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
>   08-30 15:21:05.133: W/dalvikvm(240): Exception
>   Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown during
>   Lcom/example/testfordatabase/HibernateUtility;. 08-30
>   15:21:05.133: D/AndroidRuntime(240): Shutting down VM 08-30
>   15:21:05.133: W/dalvikvm(240): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   com.example.testfordatabase.EtityDao.insert(EtityDao.java:35) 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   com.example.testfordatabase.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
>   08-30 15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408) 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816) 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   08-30 15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 08-30 15:21:05.173:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   com.example.testfordatabase.HibernateUtility.(HibernateUtility.java:31)
>   08-30 15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     ... 13 more 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration 08-30
>   15:21:05.173: E/AndroidRuntime(240):     at
>   com.example.testfordatabase.HibernateUtility.(HibernateUtility.java:27)

plz help :D
thanks

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033289/tutorials-for-using-hibernate-in-android Hibernate is not supported on Android. Did you hear differently somewhere?

Comment: maybe people didn't try hard :P

Comment: I am pretty sure Hibernate relies on bytecode manipulation. As the bytecode is completely different in Dalvik, I doubt it would ever work without a major compatibility effort.

Comment: Hibernate in fact is one of the few persistence providers (and the only JPA provider AFAIK) that actually does *not* rely on bytecode manip.  It's modus operandi is actually to use runtime generated proxies.  Just FYI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all standart  java classes are available on android. One of them  is package javax.naming  - that's why you get this porblem.   You may add missing classes from other sources though.
( or even rip them orr rt.jar ) - but doing this you may end up duplicating complete java runtime.  I find that hibernate is a bit too heavyweight for android anyway.

Comment: so you are telling (even if i run hibernate on android) my next problem will be speed and memory?

Comment: I will be your first problem.  Adding necessary classes is relatively easy and can be automated - but reflection proxies and runtime byte code manipulation will be really slow on android.