# Android DatabaseHelper using orm

Tags: android, orm, ormlite, android-sqlite

Does anyone know how to implement a DatabaseHelper on Android to usu ORM?

Comment: What specifically do you need to know how to do?

Comment: wel I was reading about using orm in android, and I want to map mai classes without having to create manualy my tables on sqlite

Comment: Start here: http://ormlite.com/android/examples/

Comment: The example on that site are fairly good at covering the basics. just mimic what is there and change is as you need to. Soon it will all make sense.

Comment: Nice! Will add ORMLite to my "things to read and investigate" list!!! Haven't come across it before!

Comment: Thanks man put this on a answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend start with [The tutorials.](http://www.ormlite.com/android/examples). They are nicely written and should help you out fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

Think you should use SQLite and maybe look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) as a starter? Alternatively use an object database ([DB4O perhaps?](http://www.db4o.com/Android/default.aspx)) - Otherwise this post appears to duplicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033289/tutorials-for-using-hibernate-in-android) which talks about hibernate for Android - I'd say it's overkill, but I'd be tempted to try DB4O!

Comment: I dunno... ORMite really helped me grasped SQLite. I found it easier to understand than Android's SQLite api. And @Gray is very active on here, which helps in a pinch.

Comment: I found the SQLite api hard to understand at first... I'd be really tempted to play with DB4O. Its interesting at the very least and I've been looking for places to use it...