# javafxport(gluon) android ios desktop orm

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

how can i use orm for javafxport? 
target app is desktop, android, ios.
which orm suggest for this?
Thankful.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? What is your use case?

Comment: 1- an orm like hibernate.
2- which db suggest for cross platform? sqlite or another db?

Comment: See the sample GluonSQLite [here](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/), and read its doc about using SQLite vs SQL. As for using hibernate on mobile devices, maybe have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257374/is-hibernate-an-overkill-for-an-android-application).